# Load json file in local project without using webserver

Tags: javascript, json

I try to load a json file from my local project which is not running on a webserver.

**test.json**

```
[{
    name : "Google",
    url : "https://www.google.com",
},
{
    name : "Bing",
    url : "https://www.bing.com",                            
}]
```

**First attempt:**

First I tried it by using the local file which is inside the project folder.

```
loadJSON("data/test.json", function(response) {

    console.log(JSON.parse(response));
});

function loadJSON(path, callback) {   

var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
    xobj.open('GET', path, true); // Replace 'my_data' with the path to your file
    xobj.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200") {
            // Required use of an anonymous callback as .open will NOT return a value but simply returns undefined in asynchronous mode
            callback(xobj.responseText);
        }
    };
    xobj.send(null);  
}
```

**Response:**

> index.html:616 Failed to load
>   file:///C:/wamp64/www/projects/Startseite/data/test.json: Cross origin
>   requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome,
>   chrome-extension, https.

Then I researched the error, set up a virtual host and changed the call to this:

```
loadJSON("http://ressources/data/test.json", function(response) {

    console.log(JSON.parse(response));
});
```

**Response**:

> Failed to load http://ressources/data/test.json: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Is it even possible to load json without using a webserver or installing browser plugins which changes the header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for JSON you can use JSONP, it's designed for cross-domain and for every url, absolute or relative.

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_jsonp.asp and 
 http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

test.html

```
<script>
    function jsonp(data){
      console.log(data)
    }
</script>
<script src="test.js"></script>
```

test.js

```
jsonp([{
  name : "Google",
  url : "https://www.google.com",
},
  {
    name : "Bing",
    url : "https://www.bing.com",
  }])
```

Comment: It seems like this does only work together with a webserver.

Comment: @Black it is not required, see modified answer, i've tested it.

Comment: but this is a javascript file not a json file. How can I add new objects to the json object now?

Comment: @Black The naming of the file doesnt matter. Just generate any javascript array that you want. Than wrap it around a function call. That's jsonp. I'm out here, nothing more i can provide to you. Maybe it doesn't fit your needs, but thats the only way doing this without a webserver.

Answer (score 0):

When running javascript on browser I think its impossible to access a file from your filesystem without webservers. If you just wanted to process these files using javascript you can do so by running javascript on your machine using node. Otherwise I am not aware of any other ways, but you may want to take a look at this :

[Local file access with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371875/local-file-access-with-javascript?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Answer (score 0):

you can't do it like that. If you can't add a web server, one option is to move JSON data into separate .js file. Since your JSON file looks like this:

```
    [{
        name : "Customer Support OTRS",
        url : "https://support.hecht-international.com",
        desc : "<strong>Customer Support OTRS</strong><br><br>Callagent<br>online",
        img : "img/otrs_thumb.PNG",
    },
{
        name : "hechtAbasConverter",
        url : "https://hac.hecht-international.com/gui/login.php",
        desc : "<strong>hechtAbasConverter - hac</strong><br><br>online",                            
        img : "img/easylife/hac.png",
    }]
```

move it to jsondata.js

```
var jsonData = [{
        name : "Customer Support OTRS",
        url : "https://support.hecht-international.com",
        desc : "<strong>Customer Support OTRS</strong><br><br>Callagent<br>online",
        img : "img/otrs_thumb.PNG",
    },
    {
        name : "hechtAbasConverter",
        url : "https://hac.hecht-international.com/gui/login.php",
        desc : "<strong>hechtAbasConverter - hac</strong><br><br>online",                            
        img : "img/easylife/hac.png",
    }]
```

and load your new file in HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/jsondata.js"></script>
```